# Current URL of the webview in Windows Phone PhoneGap app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, cordova

I am developing Windows Phone PhoneGap app. May I know how to get the current URL of the webview of the PhoneGap?

Comment: Have you tried document.location or window.location.href ?

Comment: @amorbytes I would like to know from windows phone native side.

Comment: sorry mate no idea about native windows. commented because you tagged your question under "cordova".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved the objective by handling the event through `this.CordovaView.Browser.Navigated += Browser_Navigated;` where Browser_Navigated function is as follows.

```
private void Browser_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Browser_Navigated:" + sender);

            String currentURL = "";
            Boolean isAbsolute = this.CordovaView.Browser.Source.IsAbsoluteUri;
            ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();
            ApplicationBar.Mode =ApplicationBarMode.Minimized;
            if (isAbsolute)
            {
                currentURL = this.CordovaView.Browser.Source.AbsoluteUri;



                ApplicationBarMenuItem clearCache = new ApplicationBarMenuItem();
                clearCache.Text = "Reset user settings";
                ApplicationBar.MenuItems.Add(clearCache);
                clearCache.Click += new EventHandler(OnClearCache);

                if (! currentURL.EndsWith("LoginSP.aspx")) 
                {
                    ApplicationBarMenuItem logOut = new ApplicationBarMenuItem();
                    logOut.Text = "Log out";
                    ApplicationBar.MenuItems.Add(logOut);
                    logOut.Click += new EventHandler(OnLogOut);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                currentURL = "x-wmapp1:" + this.CordovaView.Browser.Source.OriginalString;
                ApplicationBar.IsVisible = false;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("currentURL:" + currentURL);
        }
```

reference: https://github.com/dev-mobile/cordova-starter/blob/master/win7_cordova_starter/wp7_CordovaStarter/MainPage.xaml.cs

Comment: Hi, can you please let me know what code did you use in your `OnClearCache` method?